# Difference between docker volume type - bind vs volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

**TLDR**

In `docker-compose`, what's the difference between

```
volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: mydata
      target: /data
```

and

```
volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: mydata
      target: /data
```

?

**The question in long:**

When you specify the `volumes` option in your `docker-compose` file, you can use the [long-syntax style](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

According to the docs, the `type` option accepts 3 different values: **`volume`**, **`bind`** and **`tmpfs`**:

I understand the `tmpfs` option - [it means that the volume will not be saved after the container is down.](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/volumes/tmpfs/#choosing-the-tmpfs-or-mount-flag).

But I fail to find any reference in the docs about the difference between the other 2 options: `bind` and `volume`, could someone enlighten me about that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When bind mounts are files coming from your host machine, volumes are something more like the [nas](/questions/tagged/nas) of docker.

- Bind mounts are files mounted from your host machine (the one that runs your docker daemon) onto your container.
- Volumes are like storage spaces totally managed by docker.
  You will find, in the literature, two types of volumes:

  - named volumes (you provide the name of it)
  - anonymous volumes (usual UUID names from docker, like you can find them on container or untagged images)

Those volumes come with their own set of [docker commands](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume/); you can also consult this list via

```
docker volume --help
```

You can see your existing volumes via

```
docker volume ls
```

You can create a named volume via

```
docker volume create my_named_volume
```

But you can also create a volume via a `docker-compose` file

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - type: volume
          source: db-data
          target: /var/lib/mysql/data

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Where this is the part saying *please docker, mount me the volume named **db-data** on top of the container directory /var/lib/mysql/data*

```
- type: volume
    source: db-data
    target: /var/lib/mysql/data
```

And this is the part saying to docker *please create me a volume named **db-data***

```
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Docker documentation about the three mount types:

- https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/

Comment: thanks, its getting cleared now. can you also tell me, when i use the short-syntax style in my volume (path:path), to which option does the type defaults to?

Comment: None. Or actually, both. Docker is getting clever about it. If it gets a `/pat/to/file` it will be a bind. If it gets a `./relative/path/to/file` also, if it is just a `name` then docker understand it is a volume

Comment: Would be nice to mention this syntax:   `volumes: api-logs:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '${PWD}/data/logs'
`

Answer (score 36):

If I understood you correctly, you're asking in other words:  *What is the difference between Volumes and bind mounts?*

**Differences in management and isolation on the host**

*Bind mounts*  exist on the host file system and being managed by the host maintainer. 
 Applications / processes outside of Docker can also modify it.

*Volumes* can also be implemented on the host, but Docker will manage them for us and they can not be accessed outside of Docker.

**Volumes are a much wider solution**

Although both solutions help us to separate the data lifecycle from containers,
by using *Volumes* you gain much more power and flexibility over your system.

With *Volumes* we can design our data effectively and decouple it from the host and other parts of the system by storing it dedicated remote locations (Cloud for example) and integrate it with external services like backups, monitoring, encryption and hardware management.

More Volumes advantages over bind mounts:

1. No host concerns.
2. Can be managed using Docker CLI.
3. Volumes can save you some uid/gid issues related permissions which occur in cases like when a container user's uid does not match the host `gid`.
4. A new volume’s contents can be pre-populated by a container.

## Examples

Lets take 2 scenarios.

**Case 1: Web server.**
We want to provide our web server a configuration file that might change frequently. 
  For example:  exposing ports according to the current environment.
We can rebuild the image each time with the relevant setup or create 2 different images for each environment. Both of this solutions aren’t very efficient.

With *Bind mounts* Docker mounts the given source directory into a location inside the container. 
(The original directory / file in the read-only layer inside the union file system will simply be overridden).

For example - binding a dynamic port to nginx:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
     - type: bind #<-----Notice the type
       source: ./mysite.template
       target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template
    ports:
     - "9090:8080"
    environment:
     - PORT=8080
    command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.template > 
        /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

(*) Notice that this example could also be solved using Volumes.

**Case 2 : Databases.** 
Docker containers do not store persistent data: any data that will be written to the writable layer in container’s union file system will be lost once the container stop running.

But what if we have a database running on a container, and the container stops -  that means that all the data will be lost?

*Volumes* to the rescue. 
Those are named file system trees which are managed for us by Docker.

For example - persisting Postgres SQL data:

```
services:    
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - "dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    volumes:
     - type: volume #<-----Notice the type
       source: dbdata
       target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Notice that in this case, for named volumes, the source is the name of the volume
(For anonymous volumes, this field is omitted).

Comment: Do I understand correct? You used here for `dbdata` short and long syntax?

Answer (score 7):

| `Feature` | `Bind` | `Volume` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Internal soul** | Bind mounts attach a user-specified location on host filesystem to a specific point in a container file tree. | Volume attach with disk storage on the host filesystem or cloud storage. |
| **command** | `--mount type=bind,src="",dst=""` | Docker CLI `docker volume` command |
| **Dependency** | dependent on location on to the host filesystem. | Container-independent data management |
| **Separation of concerns** | No | Yes |
| **Conflict with other containers** | Yes **Example:** multiple instances of Cassandra that all use the same host location as a bind mount for data storage. In that case, each of the instances would compete for the same set of files. Without other tools such as file locks, that would likely result in corruption of the database. | No. By default, Docker creates volumes by using the `local` volume plugin. |
| **When to choose** | **1-** Bind mounts are useful when the host provides a file or directory that is needed by a program running in a container, or when that containerized program produces a file or log that is processed by users or programs running outside containers. **2-** appropriate tools for workstations, machines with specialized concerns **3-** systems with more traditional configuration management tooling. | Working with Persistent storage **1.** Databases **2.** Cloud storage |
| **When not to choose** | Better to avoid these kinds of specific bindings in generalized platforms or hardware pools. | To be written |